# SelectListItem with Boolean values, instead of strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist, selectlistitem

It is not possible to to convert SelectListItem.Value property from `string` to `Boolean`. How do I create a simple Yes/No option with the value of `true`/`false`?

```
private List<SelectListItem> getYNOptions()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> yn = new List<SelectListItem>();
            yn.Add(new SelectListItem() { 
                Text = "Yes",
                Value=true, // error
                Selected = false
            });
            yn.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text= "No",
                Value = false, // error
                Selected = false
            });
            return yn;
        } 

public ActionResult Index(){
    ViewBag.selectList = getYNOptions();
    return View();
}
```

View

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.YesOrNo, new SelectList(ViewBag.selectList,"Value","Text"), "-- Select --")
```

Comment: How about switching to Radio button(s) ?

Comment: The `Value` property is a `string` so use `Value = "False"` (or use `Boolean.ToString()`). And note its pointless to create a 2nd identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in the view from the 1st one. - just use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.YesOrNo,(IEnumerable<SeletListItem>)ViewBag.selectList, "-- Select --")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Value` property of `SelectListItem` is of type **string**. You cannot assign a boolean value to that. You may use the `ToString()` call on your boolean value.

```
new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes",   Value=true.ToString(), Selected = false }
```

or simply just use a string value

```
new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes", Value="True", Selected = false  }
```

Comment: Performance wise, is there any difference? since the first one is calling the `Boolean.ToString()` method, and the second one isn't calling any method